# Calculating the largest common divisor in awk language

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write a code for calculating the largest common divisor of two natural numbers for **awk** language, but my attempts so far have failed.

I will be grateful for your help.

My attempt:

```
awk '{ a = 5, b = 10
while (a!=0 and b!=0){
  if (a > b) { a = a % b } 
  else { b = b % a}
 } 
}' 
print (a+b)
```

Comment: You're going to show your attempt and the output, right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus My attempt:
awk '{ a = 5, b = 10
  while (a!=0 and b!=0) {
    if (a > b) { a = a % b } else { b = b % a}
  }
}'
 print (a+b)

Answer (score 3):

From https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:AWK

```
function gcd(p,q){return(q?gcd(q,(p%q)):p)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the syntax and semantic errors in your script produces:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    a = 5
    b = 10
    while ( (a!=0) && (b!=0) ) {
        if (a > b) {
            a = a % b
        }
        else {
            b = b % a
        }
    }
    print (a+b)
}
'
5
```

If the algorithm is wrong then googling "largest common divisor of two natural numbers code" produces several examples including 3 at https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/hcf-gcd. Just make the very minor tweaks to one of those (ie get rid of the variable declarations, the first printf and the scanf) to use awk instead of C syntax with your hard-coded values.